# ERROR: Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken' or its corresponding type declarations with NODE.JS and TYPESCRIPT

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

Hello friends Hello friends, I have a problem when importing jsonwebtoken, I have everything installed and everything seems to be correct but I cannot import it, the error it gives me is the following:
**TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes/auth.ts(5,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken' or its corresponding type declarations.**

Here is the code, thank you very much in advance.

**packageJson:**

```
{
"name": "back",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.24",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3"
}
```

}

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "target": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "outDir": "dist/src"
},
"lib": ["es2015"]
```

}

**Auth.ts**

```
import {Router} from 'express'
import  {Request, Response} from 'express'
import UserActions from '../actions/users';
import { UserType } from '../types/user';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'; //ERROR IMPORT:TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/routes/auth.ts(5,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken' or its corresponding type declarations.

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('PÁGINA INDEX auths!');
});
```

**PD**: I have tried everything, remove node_modules and packageJson.lock and run the npm install command again with no result

**THE PROJECT IS DOCKERIZED**
docker-compose-yml

```
  back:
    build: ./back
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./back:/back
      - /back/node_modules
    container_name: Alda_Back
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by deleting this section of code: **- /back/node_modules** from the ***docker-compose.yml***